# Uploading files but state is empty inside upload function

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I have made an example but cannot figure out the issue.
in App.tsx Upload function the state myfiles.length is always zero even though in the main component you can see the file array does get updated properly. I thought it was a scope issue so I changed to an arrow function but still the same behaviour.
App.tsx:

```
import { createRef, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import FileUploadWidgetDropzone from './FileUploadWidgetDropzone';
import { DropzoneRef } from 'react-dropzone';
import { IconButton } from '@mui/material';
import { AttachFile } from "@mui/icons-material";

function App() {
  const [myfiles, setMyFiles] = useState<File[]>([]);
  const dropzoneRef = createRef<DropzoneRef>();

  function openDialog(): void {
    if (dropzoneRef) {
      dropzoneRef.current?.open();
    }
  }

  function removeFile(file: File) {
    const newFiles = [...myfiles];
    newFiles.splice(newFiles.indexOf(file), 1);
    setMyFiles(newFiles);
    if (myfiles.length <= 4) {

    }
  }
  
  const uploadFiles = (files: File[]) => {
    debugger;
//LENGTH on myfiles is always zero
    if (myfiles.length > 4) {
      console.log("ERROR TOO MANY FILEs")
    }
// but this works correctly
    setMyFiles((prevState) => [...prevState, ...files]);
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2> boom</h2>
      <IconButton aria-label="delete" onClick={openDialog}>
          <AttachFile sx={{ transform: "rotate(45deg)", width: "2rem", height: "2rem" }} />
        </IconButton>
      <FileUploadWidgetDropzone
            acceptFiles={{
              "image/*": [],
              "application/msword": [],
              "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document": [],
            }}
            removeFile={removeFile}
            uploadFiles={uploadFiles}
            uploadedFiles={myfiles}
            maxFilesAllowed={4}
            ref={dropzoneRef}
          />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

FileUploadWidgetDropzone:

```
import CloudUploadIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CloudUpload";
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import React, { memo, useCallback } from "react";
import Dropzone, { Accept, DropzoneRef } from "react-dropzone";
import UploadedFileItem from "./UploadedFileItem";

interface Props {
  uploadedFiles: File[];
  removeFile: (file: File) => void;
  uploadFiles: (files: File[]) => void;
  acceptFiles?: Accept;
  maxFilesAllowed?: number;
}

const FileUploadWidgetDropzone = React.forwardRef<DropzoneRef, Props>(
  ({ uploadFiles, uploadedFiles, removeFile, acceptFiles, maxFilesAllowed }, ref) => {
    const dzStyles = {
      display: "none",
    };

    const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles: any) => {
      debugger;
      uploadFiles(acceptedFiles);
    }, []);

    return (
      <Dropzone
        ref={ref}
        maxFiles={maxFilesAllowed}
        noClick
        noKeyboard
        onDrop={onDrop}
        accept={acceptFiles ? acceptFiles : { "image/*": [] }}
      >
        {({ getRootProps, getInputProps, acceptedFiles, isDragActive }) => {
          return (
            <>
              <div {...getRootProps()} style={isDragActive ? { ...dzStyles } : dzStyles}>
                <input {...getInputProps()} />
                <CloudUploadIcon />
                <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                  Drop file here or
                </Typography>
              </div>
              {uploadedFiles.map((file: File, index:number) => (
                <UploadedFileItem isLoaded={false} fileName={file.name} onRemove={removeFile} key={index}/>
              ))}
            </>
          );
        }}
      </Dropzone>
    );
  }
);

export default memo(FileUploadWidgetDropzone);
```

Full code example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-breeze-xz5whf?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: This is how [state updates work in React](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value). If you need to access all files in that function, just use `[...myFiles, ...files]`

Comment: @AliNauman I think you misunderstood, state always has length of 0 no matter how many files I added, running your line would yeild only files, myfiles would be empty